# Why the DynamicMethod cant work in ExcelDna

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna, dynamicmethod

I want to create user-defined formula in Excel addin by ExcelDna ,and before I get the api response I don't know the name of the formula.All of the formula is just like that(It's worked good):

```
public static object GETROOT(object Param1, object Param2)
        {
            GetApiResult("001659ca6e3ed001d9a9be59d903a15c", new object[]
            {
                Param1,
                Param2
            });
            return "LOADING";
        }
```

The `GetApiResult` is an asynchronous function to get some data from server,and the fist parameter is a string.Based on that limits,I tried to create a `DynamicMethod` to reach my goal,this is my code:

```
public static void UDFCreate(Detail detail)
        {
            #region 
            string APIID = detail.apiIndDetail.id; // 
            string name = detail.apiIndDetail.formula;// 
            string description = detail.apiIndDetail.name;//
            List<string> paramList = new List<string>();// 
            var inputList = detail.apiIndInputs; // 
            foreach (var input in inputList)
            {
                paramList.Add(input.code);
            }
            Type[] types = new Type[paramList.Count];
            foreach (string param in paramList)
            {
                int index = paramList.IndexOf(param);
                types[index] = typeof(object);
            }
            #endregion
            DynamicMethod mult = new DynamicMethod(name, typeof(object), types, typeof(UDFGenerator));
            ILGenerator il = mult.GetILGenerator();
            //EmitTwo(il, paramList, APIID);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, APIID);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, paramList.Count);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(object));
            foreach (var param in paramList)
            {
                int index = paramList.IndexOf(param);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, index);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, index + 1);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
            }
            MethodInfo mi = typeof(UDFGenerator).GetMethod(nameof(UDFGenerator.GetApiResult));
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mi);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "LOADING");
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            List<Delegate> delegates = new List<Delegate>();            
            delegates.Add(mult.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, object, object>)));
            
            ExcelFunctionAttribute att = new ExcelFunctionAttribute
            {
                Name = name,
                Description = description,
                IsMacroType = true,
            };
            List<object> funcAttribs = new List<object>
            {
                att
            };
            
            List<object> argAttribs = new List<object>();
            foreach (var input in inputList)
            {
                ExcelArgumentAttribute atta = new ExcelArgumentAttribute();
                atta.Name = input.name;
                argAttribs.Add(atta);
            }

            List<List<object>> argAttribsList = new List<List<object>>();
            argAttribsList.Add(argAttribs);
            try
            {
                ExcelIntegration.RegisterDelegates(delegates, funcAttribs, argAttribsList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Finally,the formula is created, but when i use it in excel, there always return the error `A value used in the formula is the wrong data type`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njb9w.png)